# Cron job doesn't have permission to access file, but shell script does

Tags: bash, macos, sqlite, shell, cron

I've put together a shell script that I want executed on a schedule. Among other things, it reads a SQLite DB file and does some operations with that data. I'm having trouble getting the permissions right for the db file.

The problem line in the script `my-job.sh` is:

```
sqlite3 -json -header "/path/to/MyDatabase.db" < "/path/to/ExportScript" > "/path/to/save/output.json"
```

If I run `bash my-job.sh` OR `sh my-job.sh`, the script works fine. When the cron job runs, I see the following error (I'm saving cron job output to a file to debug this):

```
Error: unable to open database "/path/to/MyDatabase.db": authorization denied
```

Things I've tried:

- I've set permissions on `MyDatabase.db` to: 664, 666, 777, etc. None of this seems to work.
- I've logged in as root (`sudo su -`) & set up a new cron job there. Running the script manually from the cli works, but the new cron job fails in the same way.
- For both users (myself and the root user) I've tried setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of the crontab file.

Other possibly relevant details:

- MacOS 12.7
- `sqlite3` 3.37.0
- `bash` 3.2.57

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think "Authorization denied" is a permission problem. See https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/571 for example.

Comment: If it really is a permissions issue (not database authorization, as the error suggests), it might be due to flies being in "private" areas (which is separate from regular permissions). See ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673) and ["cronjobs do not run"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to grant full disk access to `cron`, as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402179/508415), shared by [@GordonDavisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) in the comment above.

A little more detail, for those who find themselves here:

1. Open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab
2. Find "Full Disk Access" in the left-hand menu
3. If `cron` is available in the right-hand list, simply check the box & save the new settings.
4. If `cron` *isn't* already in the right-hand list (longer version, with pictures [here](https://medium.com/vunamhung/granting-full-disk-access-to-cron-29d2267fbe62)):

   - click the "+" icon below the right-hand list
   - search (cmd + shift + g) for `/usr/sbin`
   - select `cron` from this folder & "Open"
   - save settings